# Ruby on Rails: How Do I Keep a Clicked link_to_current_unless from appearing outside of the Nav Bar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, nav

I have a nav bar with several links right justified along with two locale links just to the right of the brand name that display when it's not a specific URL. When I click the links right justified the links stay in the same position. When I click one of the locale links on the left the link I clicked shows as clicked but it above the nav bar.

This is what the screen looks like when the website is initially displayed.

[image]

This is what the screen looks like when the French link is clicked. It may be hard to see but the French link appears in a slightly larger font underlined. I want it to appear like the links to the right do when I click them.

[image]

Here is the code I have for the nav bar. I've also had the if statement within the container-fluid div and inbetween the two divs. I still get the same result.

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <%= link_to "#{t :geometry3d2d}", locale_root_path, class: "navbar-brand"  %>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">    

      <% if "#{request.host_with_port}" == "myrequesthost" %>
      <% else %>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><%= link_to_unless_current "#{t :english}", locale: "en" %></li>
          <li><%= link_to_unless_current "#{t :french}", locale: "fr" %></li>
        </ul>
      <% end %>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "#{t :link_home}", locale_root_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "#{t :link_store}", store_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "#{t :link_books}", store_path(anchor: "#{t :books}") %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "#{t :link_tesserart}", store_path(anchor: "tesserart") %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "#{t :link_affiliates}", affiliates_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "#{t :link_geometry}", geometry_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "#{t :link_terms}", terms_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "#{t :link_vision}", locale_root_path(anchor: "vision") %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "#{t :link_contact}", contact_path %></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<%= content_tag(:div, content_tag(:a, "", id: "top"), class: "anchor") %>
```

I have not found anything related to this issue in my web searching. The only differences between the `<ul>` in the if statement and the other one is: (1) I'm using `link_to_unless_current` instead of `link_to` and (2) I don't include class `navbar-right`. I hope that adding a class may correct this problem but not sure where to look.

Comment: It looks like the click is adding a class (maybe active or something?) that changes the color and margin/padding of that element.  Have you inspected it to see where those styles are coming from yet?

Comment: I did a search in my views, stylesheet and javascript but did not find any references to current. This is why I submitted the question. I thought I was missing something. I found out what happened by rereading the differences I posted in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use `link_to_unless_current` the selected locale link is protected and the other locale links show up as links. That functionality is not important for this project.

I decided to take another look at the differences I noted in my `<ul>` statement. I decided to change `link_to_unless_current` to `link_to` to see what happened. The locale links are behaving like the ones on the right of the nav bar and switches between English and French.